# Tiempo de Espera localstorage

Tags: ionic, angular, local-storage

Estoy trabajando en una app en ionic 3 y al hacer el login debe cargar varias variables en el localStorage para usar en el home, el problema que tengo es que luego de pasar el login entra al home rapidamente y no me carga nada porque las variables en el localstorage tardan en registrarse un segundo o dos en cargar y al ejecutar las funciones en el home no se trae nada del localstorage.

que puedo hacer para no pasar al home si todavía las variables no las ha cargado el sistema.

Comment: agrega las dos lineas en un setTimeOut, or cierto necesitas agregar el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Podría darte una respuesta mas concreta si publicaras lo que has hecho, pero te comparto una solución.

Cuando utilizas [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) de Ionic, para guardar datos existe la función **set**, que devuelve una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas), cuando esta promesa se resuelve, tienes la certeza de que el dato fue guardado, en ese momento puedes abandonar la pagina de login y viajar a otra.

```
this.storage.set('name', 'Max'),then(()=>{
  console.log("Dato guardado");
  //Viajo a otra pagina
  this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
});
```

Igualmente cuando estes en tu pagina de Home, debes consultar los datos tomando en cuenta las promesas.